# Disable command history in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to disable command history within a batch file?

After calling a my.bat, the results from calls to things like `SET /P` are pushed in to the history. So if I ask my user to enter a machine name, the history now also contains that machine name.

> P:>my.bat
>
> P:>SET /P MYENV="myenv prompt:"
>
> myenv prompt:lskdjf
>
> P:>lskdjf
>
> P:>

DOSKEY does not seem to have a way to suspend or disable pushing in to the history stack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer

```
doskey /reinstall
```

This erases the complete history.

A second way could also to start a new cmd.exe instance in your batch, this would only *remove* the history made by your `set/p` statements.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"==":historySafe" goto :historySafe
cmd /c "%~f0" :historySafe
exit /b

:historySafe
set /p var=Password
echo %var%
exit /b
```

Comment: that second bit is brilliant. Why destroy the history from before the call to my .bat file.

Comment: may be you should just do `call :historySafe` instead of calling itself and goto?

Comment: @xiaomao: With just calling :historySafe it doesn't work. The trick is to create a new cmd-context

Answer (score 0):

While in the Windows command line, press the <kbd>F7</kbd> key to view a history of all the commands that have been entered in that window. Below is a picture of what the Windows command line history box will look like when open.

[image]

Comment: But how is this related to the question, `how to disable the history` ?

Comment: While I agree that this does not contribute to answering the question, I have to admit that during decades of using Windows I have never stumbled across this feature before.